# Bullet points are not inherited style from original textbox

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have PPT add-in that split textbox into separate txtboxes by one paragraph/bullet point each. I would like to see that separate txtboxes are inherited all bullet points style/level/character/etc from original textbox. But it's not working properly with my code.
[On the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5O44.png) on left side original textbox, on the right side - what I've got with my current code.

Could you help me to understand how to make the code works properly and why:

1. characters of bullet points in Line 1 and Line 2 were changed
2. bullet point of Line 3 became slightly bigger that original
3. the spacing between bullets and text increased after splitting

Thank you

```
    for (int i = 0; i < linesBox.Count(); i++)   {
    PowerPoint.Shape textBox0 = curSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(
            Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, left, top, width, height);
    textBox0.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = linesBox[i];
    
    textBox0.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Style = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[i+1].ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Style;
    textBox0.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[i+1].ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize;
    textBox0.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[i+1].ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type;
    textBox0.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[i+1].ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character;
    textBox0.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[i+1].ParagraphFormat.RightIndent;
    textBox0.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[i+1].ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent;
    //textBox0.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel = shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[1].ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel;

    textBox0.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size;
    textBox0.TextFrame.MarginTop = 0;
    textBox0.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0;
    textBox0.TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0;
    textBox0.TextFrame.MarginRight = 0;
    textBox0.TextFrame.AutoSize = PpAutoSize.ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText;     }
```

Comment: How would you do this with the user interface? You would first format a text box, then right-click and set it as the _Default Text Box_. Then all new text boxes would match that formatting. That should work in your case, so you don't have to transfer every property from one text box to another.

Comment: If the original text box's text is all at the same bullet level and formatting, you can, I think, use the shape's .PickUp method, then use the new text box's .Apply method to copy the formatting.  Failing that, you could copy the original text box multiple times, and delete all but one line from each copy (leaving line 1 on the first copy, line 2 on the next and so on)

Comment: Thanks, @SteveRindsberg, your advice with .PickUp/.Apply helped me to solve 80% of my questions.